# fileshark.pl login using curl php

Tags: php, curl, authentication

i have big problem with login to site fileshark.pl
I use something like this

```
    function grab_page($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
    }

    function post_data($site,$data){
        $datapost = curl_init();
            $headers[] = "Content-type: application/json";
            $headers[] = "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest";
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($datapost);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($datapost);
        unset($datapost);    
    }

    $token = "";
    $data = grab_page("https://fileshark.pl/zaloguj");
    $token = cut_str($data,'_csrf_token" value="','" />'); -> take token, i need this to login post data
    post_data("https://fileshark.pl/login_check","_username=MYUSER&_password=MYPASSWORD&_csrf_token={$token}");
$data = grab_page("https://fileshark.pl/");
echo $data;
```

but when i go to normal website i am not logged ... every time not logged :/ this is post data from website...

```
https://fileshark.pl/login_check

POST /login_check HTTP/1.1
Host: fileshark.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://fileshark.pl/
Content-Length: 97
Cookie: hl=pl; _ga=GA1.2.816314079.1500843124; __gfp_64b=Ocm7N2W0C.LWu6Ga3q6MIsWU1devhoy.6XNO0Bth6q3.O7; _gid=GA1.2.234598376.1502038746; PHPSESSID=j1ch3848vrg4itpd8fgl4ul1j4; _gat=1
Connection: keep-alive
_username=MYUSER&_password=MYPASSWORD&_csrf_token=xBcS0AVCVvLnN5e2puEfxd8v_Ol6a-KG0uscwqlLU98


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 19:41:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=nsvibi4o3u5kqdc6u5rbjbi444; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: REMEMBERME=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Anyone can help me with this? When i try to other site like catshare all working but not for this site :)

Comment: You do know that any code after `return` in your functions won't ever be executed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do though.  What does _"when i go to normal website i am not logged"_ mean? Can you please let us know what you're trying to achieve and the flow of your application?

Comment: $data = grab_page("https://fileshark.pl/");
echo $data;

Comment: i try grab page when i logged , but i still not logged, always have pls login or something like this

Comment: "my code has 10 different issues that i am completely oblivious to, why isn't my code working?"

Answer (score 0):

first off, you ignore any and all setopt errors, fix that (use something like

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ){
    if(curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value)!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' .  curl_errno ($ch).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
}
```

)
.
second, obviously the csrf token is tied to a cookie session, which you completely ignore (you make no attempt to store nor resend any cookies), and without a cookie session in the login request, your csrf token will *always* be invalid, fix that (check CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to get curl to handle cookies automatically). third, you extracts the csrf token from the html with a regex, that regex will NOT decode html entities for you (like `&amp;` for `&`, `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>`, etc), so if/when the csrf token contains any such encoded characters, you will send the wrong token, fix that (see `html_entity_decode`, or better yet, use a proper html parser to extract it). fourth, you don't urlencode the username, nor the password, nor the token, so if any of those contains any characters with special meaning in urlencoded, you will send the wrong credentials, and won't get logged in, fix that (this includes `&`, `=`, spaces, all non-ascii characters, and even some ascii characters). fifth, you never stop the output buffer started in the grab_page function, you put the code to stop it after the return statement, thus that code will never be executed, fix that.  if, after fixing all those mentioned issues, you still can't get log in, let me know, and i'll dig deeper